# Scanner Class ~ hasNextDouble();

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
package pkgswitch;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Switch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double subtotal = 0.0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        outerloop:
        while(0==0){
            System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
            if (sc.hasNextDouble())
            {
                subtotal=sc.nextDouble();
            }
            else
            {
                sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Error!");
                continue outerloop;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

I'm working with learning how to catch exceptions. (I know about the `try` / `catch`)

#### Question:

How does scanner have more double tokens when it has just been initialized with no input

Comment: What do you mean scanner has been initialized with no input? Input to the scanner comes from standard input, right?

Comment: `while(0==0)` ... ಠ_ಠ ... `while(true)`

Answer (score 1):

> How does scanner have more double tokens when it has just been initialized with no input?

Your code doesn't initialize the scanner with "no input".  It initializes it with `System.in`.

What actually happens is that `sc.hasNextDouble()` attempts to read and buffer characters from the input stream ... blocking if the user hasn't typed them yet.  When the method has enough characters to determine if it has a valid `double` token, it returns `true` ... or `false`.

---

By the way:

```
   while (0 == 0) {
```

is silly.  Please don't do it.  It causes the reader to *waste his / her time*:

1. figuring out what the code is really doing, and
2. wondering whether the author doesn't understand basic Java, or has been using illegal substances while coding ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

`System.in` is an `InputStream`.  From javadoc, read "blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.  Check this out: I've added two print statements to your code.  If you run this, you'll see that the method hasNextDouble() does not return anything until after you've entered a value. So if you type a double, then hasNextDouble() will return true, and the program will set the subtotal to that value (also, not sure, but it seems to me you may want to add to subtotal instead of setting it's value).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double subtotal = 0.0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    outerloop:
    while(0==0){
        System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
        if (sc.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("has next double."); /* added */
            subtotal=sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("read double: "+subtotal);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("no next double"); /* added */
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Error!");
            continue outerloop;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all it is nice to have `while(true)` than  `while(0==0)` .When It prints "Enter Sub total" you can give a double (ex 3.0).Then `sc.hasNextDouble()` becomes true and whatever the code in if statement runs.If you give a input which is not double(ex 'k') then `sc.hasNextDouble()` becomes false and whatever in the else is running.